# Where does a question about app-server startup and how it's affected by hardware belong?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Looking for where to discuss how an SSD would improve my dev app server startup time but was [closed on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482630/running-a-full-java-stack-on-a-macbook-unibody-what-performance-gains-should-i) as off-topic.

Comment: This is a Q&A site not a `discussion` site.

Answer (score 1):

Looks very sys admin related, so should be posted to [severfault](https://serverfault.com/).

From the [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq):

> Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity.

And:

> - Server and Business Workstation operating systems, hardware, software and virtualization
> - Enterprise storage, backup, and disaster recovery
> - Network routing, switches, and firewalls
> - Operations, maintenance, and monitoring

Comment: Looks very discussiony, and not a good question anywhere. Id suggest dropping int chat to... Chat about it